# Microsoft Graph APIのcalendarViewのStartDateTimeとEndDateTime仕様について

Tags: microsoft-graph

下記を参照するとcalendarViewのStartDateTimeとEndDateTimeは、ISO8601形式にて指定するということなのですが、
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Microsoft Graphエクスプローラにてテストすると、StartDateTimeやEndDateTimeに2007-08-31T15:00:00+09:00のような「+」のタイムゾーン補正ができなくなっています。

例）

**エラーが出ない**
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@microsoft.com/calendar/calendarView?startdatetime=2020-11-16T00:00:00-09:00&EndDateTime=2020-11-16T17:30:00-09:00

**エラーが出る**
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@microsoft.com/calendar/calendarView?startdatetime=2020-11-16T00:00:00+09:00&EndDateTime=2020-11-16T17:30:00+09:00

**エラーコード**

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidParameter",
    "message": "The value '2020-11-16T00:00:00 09:00' of parameter 'StartDateTime' is invalid.",
    ～省略～
}
```

従来から「+」表現を使っていて問題なかった印象なのですが、最近になって突然エラーで弾かれるようになった印象で困っております。

対応としては補正表現を変えるなどかと思いますが、いつごろからエラーとなるようになってしまったのかを情報共有したくて投稿しました。
同じように困ってらっしゃる方がいたらいつごろからエラーになったのか等コメントいただけると幸いです。

Comment: エラーメッセージを見ると`+`が空白に変わっているように見えるので、`%2B`にエンコードしてみるとか？

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。当初はエンコードされたものでエラーが出ており、エンコードしなくても同様の挙動でした。
いま試してみると、エンコードしていれば問題ないようですね。もしかすると一時的な障害だったのかもしれません。

Comment: 追記
エンコードされたものでエラーが出た際のエラーコードも同様に+が空白に変わっていた状況でした。

Comment: 連続ですみません。エンコードしたものでもダメな場合がありました。使っているツールでもエラーの再現性が100%ではなく、同じ文字列でも起きたり起きなかったりする状況です。graphが不安定なのでしょうか。。。

Comment: そういう不安定な状況ならば、詳しい内容をMicrosoftに報告して対処してもらった方が良いと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。以前、同じMicrosoft Graphのデルタクエリの挙動が不安定な際に報告をしようとしたのですが、Microsoft Graphについてはpremierサポートを契約の上、premierサポート窓口でないと報告も聞いてもらえない対応でした。よって、今回はこちらにて相談させていただいた次第です。

Comment: それではしょうがないですね。そうするとアプリ側で問い合わせはUTCに変換して行うくらいでしょうか。